# Gym Error: NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None" in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Hi I use VSCode to work with Python. Couple days ago I installed gym for Reinforcement Learning and tried CartPole environment. When I run this simple code

```py
import gym 

env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
env.render()
env.close()
```

I received error NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None", I have spent some time to looking for solution but I didn't fine it. Therefore the question is does this issue have solution, and if yes could you point me the solution working for you.
To be more precisely I'm looking for solution which works with VSCode. If there no solution for VSCode - could you share any other solution. And one important thing - I'm working in VSCode remotely from  Windows client to the Ubuntu server.

Comment: "Working remotely on an Ubuntu server", like in ssh? Unless you've set up some sort of graphical interface (such as X forwarding), how could the window be created and displayed?

Comment: yes kind of ssh connection. 
I thought there are some VSCode extensions which can solve this. If there no solution for VSCode, maybe there are some step by step instruction (best practices) how to make it working.

Comment: Personally I'd just start an ssh session with X forwarding, but I neither use Windows nor VSCode, so I'm not sure whether that is supported via the VSCode remote development extension. I wouldn't be surprised if it was, though. There's an abundance of resources on the topic on google, so I recommend you research a setup that's most convenient for you.